# Multiple GL_QUADS in same location

Tags: python, opengl, coordinates, pyopengl

I have a health bar which is two GL_QUADS rendered at the same z coordinate, one red and one green(the green being the section of health remaining.) However, I just realize now that only 1 GL_QUAD will be visible if both are rendered in the same position. Is there a way to change the color of a section of a single GL_QUAD?

Comment: You can play with the zbuffer usage to get that effect, but it's much easier just to draw the red bit only where there's health missing. Also GL_QUADS are deprecated.

Comment: Or render the green bit at a slightly different z coordinate so that it appears slightly in front.

Comment: @Xonar I suppose that makes sense, good to know! I am aware `GL_QUADS` are deprecated, just messing around with old OpenGL till I get the hang of it :)

Comment: @ArminRigo That's what I ended up doing - probably frowned upon by a commercial standard, but good for the time being.

Comment: It sounds like you want to move the vertices, rather than change the colour on the surface of the quad. Maybe draw the red first, behind the green, but draw the green's vertices so that it decreases in size with less health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There *is* a way to change a single `GL_QUAD`'s coloring, although you don't want to do that. It would involve sliding a texture map across it by varying its texture coordinates. Not very smart.
2. What you want instead are two quads whose dimensions depend on the health. You will want to  use linear interpolation (LERP) to find the edge where one quad end and one quad begins.

Here's the math pseudocode, assuming your health bar is horizontal

```
Quad_1.x start = 0
Quad_1.x end = X%
Quad_2.x start = X%
Quad_2.x end = 1
```

`Quad_1` ends up having X% of the area, and `Quad_2` ends up having (1-X)% of the area. They both will always take up 100% of the area, and you can easily scale this to any size. Just make sure you don't have negative health or more than 100% health messing up your drawing.

**Note**: `GL_QUADS` is old and deprecated. Use `GL_TRIANGLES`, or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` if you're into efficiency (wink wink).

Alternate methods:

- You can generate a fancy procedural 2D image and use it as a texture map, which you can then use to texture a single quad. You can start by having your texture map be just a simple sliding bar based on the above explanation, but from there you can make it fancy
- You could, as Xonar and Armin Rigo have pointed out, mess with the Z value. Although if you do this as an ad-hoc fix, it may end up being more trouble down the line.

Comment: I don't think you should mess with the z value (That's asking for artefacts at the edges). I was thinking more of draw the green then the red with depth testing, but without drawing to the depth buffer. Then draw the red one with drawing to the depth buffer, but not to the screen to get correct depth testing so that you don't then draw over it if something isn't in front of it.